# React native problem saving data to firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my code.

```
import FirebaseKeys from "./config";
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

class Fire {
    constructor() {
        firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseKeys);
    }

   addPost = async ({text, localUri}) => {
       const remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(localUri)

       return new Promise((res, rej) => {
           this.firestore.collection("posts").add({
               text,
               uid: this.uid,
               timestamp: this.timestamp,
               image: remoteUri
           })
           .then(ref => {
               res(ref)
           })
           .catch(error => {
               rej(error)
           });
       });
   };

    uploadPhotoAsync = async uri => {
        const path = `photos/${this.uid}/${Date.now()}.jpg`

        return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
            const response = await fetch(uri)
            const file = await response.blob()

            let upload = firebase.storage().ref(path).put(file)

            upload.on(
                "state_changed",
                 snapshot => {},
                err => {
                     rej(err)
            },
            async () => {
                const url = await upload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                res(url);

                }
            );
        });
    };
```

What I have noticed is there is no problem uploading image on uploadImageAsync but when it comes to addPost method it does not create a collection named "post".

what should I do with this? thankyou in advance. btw I am not using expo on this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the collection that your `addPost` method is trying to create is called "posts", not "post". When it comes to Firestore, always check that your security rules allow for this user to write to that path.

It would also be nice to see the usage of `addPost`, and see what its `res` and `rej` return.

Comment: Hello, recently I also have noticed that some of transaction using that addpost method was successful datas are being shown, but most of the time it does not apply on the database

Comment: Can you show your configured security rule for this collection, and the usage of the `addPost` method?

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

Here it is sir